# Naive Schur-Weyl duality for the 0-Hecke algebra

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, hecke-algebras

The 0-Hecke algebra $\mathcal{H}_n(0)$ is the $\Bbb{C}$-algbra generated by elements $T_1,
\dots, T_{n-1}$ satisfying the braid relations
and the idempotency relations $T_i^2 = T_i$.
It is known that $\mathcal{H}_n(0)$ "acts" on the
set of permutations ${\frak{S}}_n$ by *partial bubble anti-sorting*: For $\sigma \in {\frak{S}}_n$ and $T_i \in \mathcal{H}_n$ with $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ define

\begin{equation}
\sigma \cdot T_i
= \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 
\sigma \tau_i
&i \notin \mathrm{Des}_R(\sigma) \\
\sigma 
&i \in \mathrm{Des}_R(\sigma)
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

where $\tau_i =(i, i+1)$ is the $i$-th simple transposition and where $\mathrm{Des}_R(\sigma) = \big\{k \, \big| \, \sigma(k) > \sigma(k+1) \big\}$ is the right-descent set of the permutation $\sigma$.

Take a finite dimensional complex vector space $V$
equipped with a fixed basis $B = \{v_1, \dots, v_n \}$. For $N \geq 1$ encode decomposable tensors of $V^{\otimes N}$ by permutations, i.e.
for $\sigma \in {\frak{S}}_n$ define
$\Bbb{v}[\sigma] := v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots
\otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$. Now set

\begin{equation}
T_i \big(\Bbb{v}[\sigma] \big) \, := 
\Bbb{v}\big[ \sigma \cdot T_i \big]
\end{equation}

and extend this formula by linearity
to all of $V^{\otimes N}$ to obtain a complex representation of $\mathcal{H}_n(0)$.
I'll write $V^{\otimes N}_B$
in order to recognize the dependency of this representation on the basis choice.

**Question:** What can be said about the algebra of $\mathcal{H}_n(0)$-intertwinors

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{End}_{\, \mathcal{H}_n(0)} \big[ V^{\otimes N}_B \big]
\end{equation}

Is there an analogue of classical Schur-Weyl duality at play here?

**Disclamation:** The question, as formulated, has serious problems: The vector space space spanned by the tensors $\Bbb{v}[\sigma]$
for $\sigma \in {\frak{S}}_n$ clearly has dimension $n!$ and not
$n^N$. Furthermore the index $n$ in $\mathcal{H}_n(0)$ ought to match the
tensor power, not the dimension of the original vector space $V$.
So the entire set-up is a bit misbegotten.

Nevertheless, the question about whether the 0-Hecke algebra $\mathcal{H}_0(n)$ has a version of Schur-Weyl duality still stands.
Indeed RVK's comments may point to an answer. Perhaps this is a case of *stone-soup*. As someone who (twenty years ago) studied quantum groups, I feel a bit ashamed that I didn't think of *$R$-matrices* to begin with.

Thanks, ines.

Comment: Is the 0-Hecke algebra also what is called the degenerate Hecke algebra (I might be used to a slightly different presentation)? If so, the (now classical?) paper by Rouquier-Chuang: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~rouquier/papers/dersn.pdf might be relevant. (I dont remember the details, but this all looks vaguely familiar. I could be way off though).

Comment: Rouquier-Chuang seem to be considering an affine version of what I posted about; so their $H_n(1)$ seems to contain $\mathcal{H}_n(0)$ as a subalgebra. If they have a version of Schur-Weyl duality for $H_n(1)$ then this ought to help. Thanks.

Comment: There is a Schur-Weyl duality between the degenerate affine Hecke algebra $H_n(1)$ and the ${\frak{sl}}_n$-Yangian according to this paper https://web.northeastern.edu/iloseu/Yi14.pdf. The basic point seems to be that the (affine, degenerate) Hecke generators should act by an appropriate R-matrix.

Comment: Well, yes, basically you are going to have a braid group action on any braided monoidal category (so these show up w/ reps of algebraic groups, Yangians and their brethren). The idempotent relation (quadratic relation for Hecke algebra and variations thereof) occurs in Type A (is the projection onto a factor of tensor of “fundamental representation”. The “affine operators” occur when you tensor said fundamental rep w/ fixed infinite dim module (like a Verma) - they are the action of the ribbon element/Casimir. Very vague, but that’s all I remember (mostly) of this. Sorry!